# Java: Obtain matched string from an input

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to obtain the string that my matcher is able to find using my provided expression. Something like this..

```
if(matcher.find())
    System.out.println("Matched string is: " + ?);
```

What would be the appropriate code for this? According to [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) the

```
matcher.group();
```

method returns only the provided input same as

```
matcher.group(0);
```

Thanks in advance..

Edit:

Example follows below:

```
private static String fileExtensionPattern = ".*<input type=\"hidden\" name=\".*\" value=\".*\" />.*";
private static Matcher fileXtensionMatcher;
private static String input = text  "<html><body><table width="96"><tr><td><img src=&quot;file:/test&quot;  /><input type="hidden" name="docExt" value=".doc" />Employee Trv Log 2011 Training Trip.doc</td></tr></table></body></html>"

private static void findFileExtension() {
    System.out.println("** Searching for file extension **");
    System.out.println("Looking for pattern: " + fileExtensionPattern);
    fileXtensionMatcher = fileXtensionExp.matcher(input);

    if(fileXtensionMatcher.find()) {
        //the extension expression is contained in the string
        System.out.println("Extension expression found.");
        System.out.println(fileXtensionMatcher.group());
    }
}
```

The obtained result is:

```
text    "<html><body><table width="96"><tr><td><img src=&quot;file:/test&quot;  /><input type="hidden" name="docExt" value=".doc" />Employee Trv Log 2011 Training Trip.doc</td></tr></table></body></html>"
```

Comment: Did you try it? If you did, you would have known that `matcher.group()` will do exactly what you need.

Comment: @Marcelo please read comment to last answer

Comment: Added an answer after seeing your source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you added the source code, I can assure you the `group()` returns the whole input string because it matches your regular expression. If you want just the `<input>` element use:

```
private static String fileExtensionPattern = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\".*\" value=\".*\" />";
```

Or use:

```
private static String fileExtensionPattern = ".*(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\".*\" value=\".*\" />).*";
. . .
System.out.println(fileXtensionMatcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was the regular expression with the ".*". As you said it was matching the whole string, and group() was returning the whole string as a result. Removing the ".*" from beginning and end gave me the result.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think that `group()` returns the input?

According to [the JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29):

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

In other words: it returns *that part* of the input that was matched.

Comment: That is the result that I have, unfortunately.

Comment: @NecArn: please provide an example, because I know for a fact that `group()` returns the mached part of the input.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim, the name of the method was not clear enough for me. Without knowledge of groups of results, it lead me to believe that the error was in the method instead of the provided regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your update it seems like you need matcher groups. Also you need to make your matches non-greedy (`.*?` instead of `.*`). Try this:

```
private static String fileExtensionPattern = 
    ".*<input type=\"hidden\" name=\".*?\" value=\"(.*?)\" />([^<]*)";

// etc.
private static void findFileExtension() {

     // etc.
     if(fileXtensionMatcher.find()) {
        // etc.
        System.out.println(fileXtensionMatcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(fileXtensionMatcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This result actually saves me the effort of extracting the extension in the next result using (.*?) for value field and group(2).

Comment: The main problem is the extraneous `.*` at either end of the regex, as @Marcelo said.  But that's a very good point about making the reset of the quantifiers non-greedy.  You could use `\"[^\"]*\"`, too, for the attribute values.